# It seems my qsort didn't give correct result why?

Tags: c, qsort

this is my compare function:

```
   int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
    {
        ptnode * ia = (ptnode*)a;
        ptnode * ib = (ptnode*)b;
        return (int)(100.f*ia->x - 100.f*ib->x );
    }
```

and I called qsort as:

```
qsort(sortbase,index,sizeof(ptnode),compare);
```

sortbase is an array of my struct ptnode, defined as:

```
typedef struct node
{
    struct node  *pre1;
    struct node  *pre2;
    struct node  *pre;
    double          x;
    double y;
    double maxlength;
} ptnode;
```

sortbase is like this:

```
struct node * sortbase[1000];
```

I want to sort them by their x value,but before and after qsort, there's nothing changed,

whY? thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the values in your array (or at least the "x" values)? What is "index" set to when you call qsort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compare function receives a pointer to the 2 elements you need to compare. Since your elements are pointers, the compare function needs to handle pointer to pointers.

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    ptnode * ia = *(ptnode**)a;
    ptnode * ib = *(ptnode**)b;
    return (int)(100.f*ia->x - 100.f*ib->x );
}
```

Comment: Beat me. I was typing a similar answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

`qsort` passes to `compare` the *address* (not value) of each element of the array, i.e., it passes a pointer to a pointer to a `ptnode`.  You need to change the first line of `compare` to:

```
ptnode * ia = *(ptnode**)a;
```

and likewise for the second line.

Comment: @user969986: And just how are you determining that?  Are you sure it returns the correct values when called by `qsort` and that the `x` values that it's comparing at that time are correct?